# Disable Audio Content in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio-streaming

I browse on my Win 7 computer using Google Chrome.  At the same time I listen to music using iTunes.  Sometimes I will get to a website with audio content and Chrome's audio interrupts iTunes'.

Is there an option in Chrome to disable audio output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your OS using the audio mixer or control panel. The change must he performed while Chrome is playing audio, and should be permanent regardless of OS.

Windows:
Doubleclick the speaker icon in your tray, open up the mixer and slide Chrome's volume slider down.

Linux:
Open pulseaudio volume control and mute Chrome.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was unaware of the power of the Mixer feature.